# Using R and R-SQL API to execute SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, r

For an assignment, I am supposed to use SQL to get a list of unique values from a table as a vector in R. I wrote the following code in R:

```
selection = dbSendQuery(con, statement = "SELECT user_id FROM twitter_message")

user_id = c(dbFetch(selection))
```

I am supposed to then randomly generate 3 values, preferably using the sample() function. However, when I do that, it generates vectors the size of the original vector (approximately 500 values) rather than selecting 3 values from the vector. I do not know if the error is from how I put the data in a vector or not. I tried writing the following code:

```
sample(user_id, size = 3, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)
```

However, I get an the error:

> Error in sample.`int(length(x), size, replace, prob)` :
> cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'

Answer (score 0):

Need to sample from rows not from your dataframe.

```
user_id[sample(nrow(user_id), 3, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL),]
```

Comment: @grandwizard, does the above answers your question?